# Scraping a page from a secure URL which is possibly using a session ID

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize, referrer, scrapy

How to scrape a page like this: https://www.procom.ca/JobList.aspx?keywords=&Cities=&reference=&JobType=0

It is secure, and looks like it requires a referrer. I can't get anything using wget or httplib2.

If you go through this page, you get a list and it works on a browser but not the command line.
https://www.procom.ca/jobsearch.aspx

I am interested in command line fetching.

Comment: look at fiddler--it lets you inspect and replay requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, it requires a referer. This works:

```
   import urllib2
   urlopen = urllib2.urlopen
   Request = urllib2.Request
   url = 'https://www.procom.ca/JobList.aspx?keywords=&Cities=&reference=&JobType=0'
   headers =  {'Referer' : 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'}
   req = Request(url, None, headers)
   handle = urlopen(req)
   print handle.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

What data are you sending in POST or Get, I would recommend look thru the POST/GET messages in Firebug Net Panel, in that page there are many hidden values which I think are time dependent and changes on each page load and may be valid once so load page , get those values and send them with POST messages e.g. see these

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwODIzNjMxMzEPFgIeEUdyaWRTb3J0RGlyZWN0aW9uCyo..." />
```